# Jenkins master failover scenario

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, high-availability, cloudbees, gearman

We are looking at Open source Jenkins masters failover scenario, and currently backing up jenkins jobs and configurations using SCM sync plugin. any ideas on how to restore Jenkins for high availablity
 when master goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker images work great for this. In essence the master is just an image which you configure with all your jobs. Logging of course should not be stored on the docker image but piped to AWS S3 or some datastore.

Each job you run launches a new docker slave to handle that task. Offers HA with lots of room for horizontal scaling.

If docker/containers is not your thing, configuration management is the way to go (chef, puppet, ansible). Take your pick and use these tools to build out your consistent Jenkins master and restore from latest backup.

Comment: we are looking at zero downtime, that rules out getting from backup and restore. between the two servers, probably will go with HA proxy for trying. AWS S3/Docker images we are not there yet.